# Is there a function to clear mp_exp_t type variable?

Tags: c++, gmp

The problem is that my program uses lots of memory. I couldn't find anything suspicious except this `mp_exp_t` type variable. In GMP library some variables need to be cleared after use, is `mp_exp_t` one of them?

Comment: If you look at gmp.h, you'll see that it is just an int (or long), nothing fancy.

Comment: In addition to @MarcGlisse comment, from the documentation: "The floating point functions accept and return exponents in the C type `mp_exp_t`. Currently this is usually a long, but on some systems it’s an int for efficiency."

Comment: Thanks guys, I just wanted to be sure.